# Display the output on terminal and redirect it to a file without using TEE

Tags: android, bash

Can we display the Output of a command to terminal and redirect it to a file at the same time WITHOUT USING TEE.

Commands in "android-cts" fail to run when i use tee to redirect the output to a file

Answer (score 0):

It's quite strange, but if your command is ls and your output file a, you can try :

> (rm a;touch a;tail -f a &);ls >a